# Chrome (ONLY!) experiencing a NullReferenceException with a redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Okay, out front here: this works 100% in every other browser out there. But Chrome (specifically, and variants thereof such as Vivaldi and Blisk) fails spectacularly with a `NullReferenceException` being thrown *after* the redirect gets touched. Whisky-Tango-Foxtrot.

Current project:

- DotNet 4.6.2
- MVC 5
- ASP.NET MVC 5 HTML5 Boilerplate

I am filling several lists through a controller:

```
public static class SelectLists {
  public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProvinceList() {
    return new List<SelectListItem> {
      new SelectListItem() {Text = @"British Columbia", Value = "2"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = @"Alberta", Value = "1"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = @"Saskatchewan", Value = "5"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = @"Manitoba", Value = "3"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = @"Ontario", Value = "4"}
    };
  }
  public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList() {
    return new List<SelectListItem> {
      new SelectListItem() {Text = @"ClientType1", Value = "1"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = @"ClientType2", Value = "2"},
    };
  }
}
```

I then pull them in through the model:

```
[Validator(typeof(IndexValidator))]
public class IndexViewModel {
  public int Province { get; set; }
  public int Client { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProvinceList => SelectLists.ProvinceList();
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList => SelectLists.ClientList();
}
```

And then dump the model into the View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Process", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline body-form", role = "form" })) {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Province, Model.ProvinceList, "« ‹ Select › »", new { @class = "form-control required" })<br />
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Province)<br />
  foreach(var item in Model.ClientList) {
    @Html.RadioButton("Client", item.Value, new {id = item.Text}) <label for="@item.Text">@item.Text</label><br />
  }
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Client)<br />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
}
```

Once submitted, the form is validated:

```
public class IndexValidator : AbstractValidator<IndexViewModel> {
  public IndexValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Province).NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must choose your province.");
    RuleFor(x => x.Client).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Are you [client type 1] or [client type 2]?");
  }
}
```

And then I process them:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Process(IndexViewModel model) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    switch(model.Client) {
      case 1:
        return Redirect("https://example1.com");
      default:
        return Redirect("https://example2.com");
    }
  }
  return View("Index", model);
}
```

So the really weird thing is when I step through with the debugger, *everything goes identical with every browser*, even to were the debugger hits the closing tag of the `Process()` method. As in, the debugger clearly moves through the correct redirect, showing that the `switch` had content to act upon.

But once the method has been fully processed, Chrome (specifically, and variants thereof such as Vivaldi and Blisk) causes a `NullReferenceException` in the code, preventing the redirect from redirecting. To be utterly clear: once the debugger hits the closing bracket of the method, *the very next step (F11) is the `NullReferenceException`*. ***NO OTHER BROWSER DOES THIS***.

Using a different type of redirect such as

```
return new RedirectResult("https://example.com/", false);
```

elicits the same issue.

I am utterly mystified as to how Chrome is able to trigger such an error all by itself.

---

**Update:**

Replacing the `switch` with the following Ternary:

```
return Redirect(model.Client == 1 ? "https://example1.com/" : "https://example2.com/");
```

makes no difference - Chrome still throws a NullReferenceException on exiting the method. All other browsers handle the redirect just fine.

---

**Update 2:**

Ummm… full disclosure includes me now mentioning that I am using the ASP.NET MVC HTML5 Boilerplate. This template also comes with a little gem called the Content Security Policy. While it is supposed to increase security, it also increases occurrences of fist-through-monitor frustrations.

In this case, under Chrome (and why only Chrome?) the CSP is preventing outgoing redirects from working. As in, it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Why outgoing redirects? Why only on Chrome? Who the f**k knows. Especially since it is Chrome-specific, and does not affect any other browser. Right now I have CSP turned off entirely, and Chrome now works with a redirect.